# Open CV to Capture Unique Objects from a Video

Tags: python, opencv

I was doing a frame slicing from the OpenCV Library in Python, and I am successfully able to create frames from the video being tested on.

I am doing it on a CCTV Camera installed at a parking entry gateway where the video plays 24x7, and at times the car is standing still for good number of minutes, leading to having consecutive frames of the same vehicle.

My question is how can I create a frame only when a new vehicle enters the parking lot?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is for code related queries. I suggest you try some code and share your results and your problems before posting anything here. That being said, you can start with object detection tutorials like [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/18/real-time-object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/) and then do tracking with [sort](https://github.com/abewley/sort). Many pre trained models are available that include the cars class so you won't even need to train a new model.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to detect license plates, etc? Or just notice if something happens? For the latter, you could use a very simple approach. Take an average of say the frames of the last 30 seconds and subtract that from a current frame. If the mean absolute average of the delta image is above a threshold, that could be the change you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some simpler motion detection with opencv, it's nicely explained in https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/

So if you have a picture of the background as reference, you can compare each new image to the background and only save the image if it's different enough from the background (hopefully only when a car entered). Then make this the new background and reset for a new car when the new images again start looking like the original background.

Hopefully I stated my idea clear enough and that link provides enough information to implement it. If not just ask for a clarification!

Comment: Yes, i read through and i chose the motion detection approach itself. Thank you. I have found a reference which opens the webcam as a video source during execution. How can i make it run over a video that is already there in my system ? Sharing the link as well:http://www.technicdynamic.com/2017/08/28/python-motion-detection-with-opencv-simple/

Comment: You mean a video file? You can check the documentation for video capture at https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to have a specific xml to detect only cars.You can get it from the [here](https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades/blob/master/cars.xml).I have developed a code just to uniquely identify and count the cars that are visible to the cctv you are using,sometimes it totally depends on the frame rate and detection too,so you can control the frame rate and also the total count variable.

```
import cv2
cascade_src = 'cars.xml'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp_of_ur_cctv')
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_src)
prev_count=0
total_count=0
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 1)
    if len(cars)>prev_count:
        diffrence=len(cars)-prev_count
        total_count=total_count+diffrence
        #here yo can save unique new entry and possibly avoid the recursive ones
        print(total_count)
    for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)      
    prev_count=len(cars)
    cv2.imshow('video', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```